# Sorting names in a list alphabetically?

Tags: android, list, sorting

Can you please help me for sorting a list alphabetically

My code

```
emailList.add(contact.getUserName());                               
String[] emails = new String[emailList.size()];
emailList.toArray(emails);
namesList.add(name);

Collections.sort(emailList, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String name1 = (String) o1;
        String name2 = (String) o2;
        return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2);
    }
});

System.out.println("namesList.toString() = " + namesList.toString());
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't need to create a new comparator. Just call `Collections.sort(emailList);`.

**UPDATE:**

```
Collections.sort(emailList, new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String text1, String text2)
    {
        return text1.compareToIgnoreCase(text2);
    }
});
```

Comment: If the comparison needs to be case insensitive, then the default comparator won't work.

Comment: And if you are using that set of items to populate a listview, dont forget to do `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to update the ui.